# Spring Framework: Ignoring TypeMismatchException

Tags: spring, rest, type-mismatch

In Spring Controller, I have configured a global exception handler. I am using custom type (Ip Address Type) for Spring Controller PathVarilable. When Spring converts incoming String to IpAddress type, a validation exception (custom) is thrown. But Spring ignores the exceptions and throws it's own TypeMismatchException with Errorcode of 400. 
I want to throw my own exception with my own error code. Is there a way to override this behavior? I tried throwing custom exception from global exception handler but Spring still overrides it.

Comment: Spring makes a pretty good job to not interfere with the programmer intentions. However in this case it makes sense to translate conversion exceptions to a well defined exception, which will result in *400 Bad Request* response. Your original exception will be probably set as the cause of the `TypeMismatchException` if your exception extends `IllegalArgumentException` or `ConversionException`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/TypeConverterSupport.java#L76

Answer (score 0):

```html
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    public RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    // API

    // 400

    /**
     * 自定义类型转换错误
     */
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleTypeMismatch(TypeMismatchException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
   HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
     
     
     if (!(request.getHeader("accept").indexOf("application/json") > -1 || (request
    .getHeader("X-Requested-With")!= null && request
    .getHeader("X-Requested-With").indexOf("XMLHttpRequest") > -1))) {
   // 如果不是异步请求
   // Apply HTTP status code for error views, if specified.
   // Only apply it if we're processing a top-level request.
            final String bodyOfResponse = "Illegal Arguments";
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, headers, status, request);
  } else {// JSON格式返回
            Map<String,Object> bodyOfResponse = new HashMap<String,Object>();
         bodyOfResponse.put("message", "Illegal Arguments");
         bodyOfResponse.put("code",400);
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, headers, status, request);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. The chinese comments mean nothing to the large majority of the audience.